# I want to find and replace an ordered list in word from the . to the )

Tags: ms-word

I have tried [0-9] and checked the use wildcard box but it replaces the individual numbers with the literal [0-9] string. How do I replace with the number it found plus a character?

Comment: Is this related to programming (or) something else? If programming, which language you are using? more details will be useful.

Comment: And you're doing this in MS Word?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft's Word supports regex for find and replace.  I simply want to change 1. 2. 3. etc to 1) 2) 3)

Answer (score 0):

Backreferences. Your unspecified environment may or may not support them, but if it does, you would:

```
replace \([0-9]*\) 
with    \1 <then, whatever the character you want is>
```